# nested query on the same table

Tags: mysql, subquery

do you think a query like this will create problem in the execution of my software?
I need to delete the all the table, except the last 2 groups of entries, grouped by the same time of insert.

```
delete from tableA WHERE time not in
                (
                  SELECT time FROM
                  (select distinct time from tableA order by time desc limit 2 
                  ) AS tmptable
                );
```

Do you have better solution? I'm using mysql 5.5

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your query, but I prefer using an `OUTER JOIN/NULL` check (plus it alleviates the need for one of the nested subqueries):

```
delete a
from tableA a 
  left join 
  (
      select distinct time 
      from tableA 
      order by time desc 
      limit 2 
  ) b on a.time = b.time
where b.time is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ef72/1)